# How to track DOM element's class attribute changes and apply same on some element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-components

I have a `angularjs` component, In the component I have following `HTML`

```
<div id="panel" class="hide-div">
  <div id="viewPort" class="hide-div">
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

There is a third party `javascript/jquery` library, I don't have control over third party library, third-party library removes the class `hide-div` from the `viewPort` on some server-side event.
 `hide-div` class hides the element.
 Now my requirement is to remove the `hide-div`
class from `panel`, when it is removed from `viewPort`. In short if `viewPort` is hidden then panel should be hidden and if `viewPort` is visible then `panel` should be visible too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, hook into that other library to get a proactive notification from it when it shows/hides that div.

If you can't do that, you can use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for changes to the attributes on the element, and then show/hide your other element depending on whether that element has the relevant class.

Example:

```js
// Your code
var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
    var source = $("#source");
    var target = $("#target");
    target.toggleClass("hide-div", source.hasClass("hide-div"));
});
observer.observe($("#source")[0], {attributes: true});

// This code emulates the library that you don't control
var handle = setInterval(function() {
  $("#source").toggleClass("hide-div");
}, 800);
$("#btn-stop").on("click", function() {
  clearInterval(handle);
});
```

```css
.hide-div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-stop">Stop</button>

<div id="source">This is the source element that the library changes</div>
<div id="target">This is the target element that we update when the source element changes</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: don't have control over a library.

Comment: @Govinda - That situation is what the second paragraph above is for, the one starting *"If you can't do that..."*

Comment: Do you know any other way to do the same. angularjs way?

Comment: @Govinda - The mutation observer part would be the same. The show/hide part would be specific to your exact Angular code. **If** you can't figure out the show/hide part, post a question with a [mcve] in it demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I tried your solution, it is working fine. But test cases are failing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398703/jasmine-how-to-mock-mutationobserver?noredirect=1#comment87963551_50398703