# Jasmine: How to mock MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, mutation-observers

I have a angularjs component,

**HTML template**

```
<div id="panel" class="hide-div">
   <div id="viewPort" class="hide-div">
    ...
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myController = function() {
    var ctrl=this;
    ctrl.$onchanges = function() {

    }

    var source = $("#viewport");
    var target = $("#panel");
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
       target.toggleClass("hide-div", source.hasClass("hide-div"));
     });
    observer.observe($("#viewport")[0], {attributes: true});
}

var config = {
    controller: [myController],
    templateUrl: "temp/abc.html",
    bindings: {
        id: "<",
        name: "<"
    }
};

directives.component("myComponent", config);
```

Here I have `MutationObserver` which add/removes the class by observing other elements attribute

**Jasmine script**
Here I am setting up the script for all the test cases

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,  $compile, _$componentController_, ...){
    $templateCache.put("temp/abc.html", "<div><div id='panel' /><div id='viewport' /></div>");
    rootScope = $rootScope;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $componentController = _$componentController_;
    element = angular.element("<my-component></my-component>");
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    ctrl = $componentController("myComponent", null, componentBining);
}));
```

Here I am getting the following error,

`NotFoundError: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8 in temp/abc.html observe@[native code]`

Comment: try fixing your quotes:
$templateCache.put("temp/abc.html", "<div><div id='panel' /><div id='viewport' /></div>");

Comment: I did try it as well as espacing the quote. But it's still throwing same error.

Comment: try to create a plunker (plnkr.co) demonstrating the issue, as it is I can't replicate the problem.

Comment: Have u tried creating mutation ibserver in global window context?

Comment: You might be able to copy the implementation from JSDOM: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/04f6c13f4a4d387c7fc979b8f62c6f68d8a0c639/lib/jsdom/living/mutation-observer/MutationObserver-impl.js#L14

Answer (score 1):

JSDom globals are different from what you would expect.

The answer to this question have to shift the focus from "**How to mock** MutationObserver?" to "**Why to mock** it at the first place?"

The MutationObserver is externally implemented for you, and hopefully, it's working just fine. So I wouldn't test it as part of my test scope. Instead I would just extract the callback

```
const triggerHandler = function() {
       target.toggleClass("hide-div", source.hasClass("hide-div"));
     }

 var observer = new MutationObserver(triggerHandler);
```

and trigger the handler manually to test the effect.

Also, you can mock the MutationObserver with `jest.fn()`, like

```
global.MutationObserver = jest.fn(()=>{
  return {...}
})
```